# Dgrid change page show busy or standby indicator

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I have dgrid with paging, 50 rows per page, and using a memory store
The last 2 columns are editable select and filtering select, so when I change page it takes some time.
The problem is that there is not indication to the user that something is happening.
No loading message or a spinning image.
So I want to know if there is an event that fires up before the change of page, so I can manually show a spinner.
So far I have not been able to find such an event.
I used firebug to listen to all click that fires up when I click on the grid, and clicked on the next button to see what will happen.
The only event that fired up was after the rendering of the page. Before the rendering I got nothing.
So how can I show a busy indicator to user when I change page on the dgrid?

Comment: @Christofors: Did you find anything for this?

Answer (score 0):

A div with the class `dgrid-loading` is added to the content area of the grid when Pagination loads a new page, and that div spans the full width and height of the content area.  You can add styles to this class to add a loading indicator.

You can also add a loading message via the grid's `loadingMessage` property.

There's an explanation and demonstration of the loading node in the [Grids and Stores tutorial](http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.4/grids_and_stores/) in the Customizing Messages section.

Comment: Thank for the answer but this is not happening in my case. When I change page no loading indicator is shown.  Also no loadingMessage is shown although I have a value on the corresponding property. I will check to see for the div.dgrid-loading, maybe it is not showing because of css conflict.

Comment: I didn't say it shows anything by default - I said this is what's available for you to customize to show what you want.

Comment: "You can also add a loading message via the grid's loading Message property." I think this should be shown by default, any way I droped dojo. Thanks for the answer.